# What happens to multiple references to the same object in JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to access some Java code from C++. Object references returned by the JNI must be cleaned up, but what happens if multiple methods return the same Java object? Do I need to call Delete on each of them?

E.g. `java.nio.Buffer` has a method `clear()` that clears the buffer and returns itself.

If I first create a buffer with JNI, then call `clear()`, do I need to clean up both `jobjects`, or am I good to only clean up one of them?

Comment: 'Object references returned by the JNI must be cleaned up': no. They will all be released when the JNI method returns. You may need to release them ahead of time if you use a lot, but it usually isn't necessary.

Comment: In my use case I'm running out of local reference count before returning.

Comment: So in that case you need to release them. The easy way is by scoping them with the local-frame API methods. When you release the frame, everything acquired in it gets released. Duplicates included, automatically.

Comment: @user207421 I'm aware there are additional helpers that help managing references, but I have to do it manually in this case.

Comment: If you're able to run your code on Android you could use the `dumpReferenceTables` method in `android.os.Debug` before and after calling `clear()`. It's marked `@hide`, but you can call it through reflection or JNI.

Answer (score 0):

In JNI you have Java objects and Java object references. A `jobject` is an object reference that points to a Java object and that you can release with `DeleteLocalRef` if you don't need it anymore.

Calling `clear()` on a `Buffer` object will create a new reference for the returned object, even if it actually points to the same object. So yes, if you run out of local references, you should release all references to your `Buffer` but the one, you're working with.